# How can I create a subscript with a getter that returns an optional, but a setter that returns a non-optional

Tags: swift, subscript

I am writing a custom collection called `TriangularArray<T>`. It represents a structure like this:

```
     x
    x x
   x x x
  x x x x
 x x x x x
```

where each `x` is an element in the array. I can access the elements with a row number and an index number, both zero-based. For example, accessing (4, 2) of the following:

```
     a
    b c
   d e f
  g h i j
 k l m n o
```

will result in `m` (5th row, third value in that row).

I used a `[[T]]` as the backing array and I wrote a subscript like this:

```
subscript(_ row: Int, _ index: Int) -> T? {
    get {
        // innerArray is the [[T]] used for backing
        if row < 0 || row >= innerArray.count {
            return nil
        }
        if index < 0 || index > row {
            return nil
        }
        return innerArray[row][index]
    }

    set {
        if row < 0 || row >= innerArray.count {
            return
        }
        if index < 0 || index > row {
            return
        }
        innerArray[row][index] = newValue!
    }
}
```

The logic is that the subscript will return `nil` if you access a non-existent row and index, like (1, 3). However, by making the subscript return `T?`, the `newValue` in the setter also becomes optional, and I have to force unwrap it.

I really want compile-time checking of this kind of thing:

```
triangularArray[0, 0] = nil // this should be a compile time error
```

I tried looking this up on Google but I only found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342620/swift-subscript-with-different-signature-for-the-getter-and-setter), which is very outdated. Surely we can do better in Swift 4.2, right?

Comment: I don't think that the situation changed. Subscript getters/setters still return/take the identical type.

Comment: @MartinR I see. Maybe I can make use of some other language feature to achieve a similar kind of aesthetic, and disallowing `nil` at the same time...

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is to define two subscript methods: One to get/set a non-optional value, and another get-only subscript returning an optional (like the “safe array accessor” currently discussed at https://forums.swift.org/t/add-accessor-with-bounds-check-to-array/16871)

Comment: Indeed, the way the stdlib handles this is by making such optional-returning accessors get-only, for example `(Bidirectional)Collection`'s `first` and `last` properties.

Comment: Another option (also from that Swift Forum discussion) is to define an accessor method `elementAt(row:index:) -> T?` – The other question is if you really want the *setter* to ignore invalid indices silently, or if that should crash.

Comment: With this code, you can't add new *lines* to `innerArray`. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @Carpsen90 the collection will always have a fixed number of rows, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unfortunately impossible to do with Swift (and other languages working with dynamic arrays) for the reason that the size of the array is dynamic and is not know at compile time (it can be initialized with any value when the program is running).
For example, if the `TriangularArray<T>` is of size `1`, then `[0, 0]` *is a valid element*, and the compiler cannot know that in advance.
In the standard library, there's no compile-time error when you try to access an array like `array[-1]` - this will always compile but will always result in a runtime error.

I think the solution that you currently have using optionals seems to be the best scenario here. You also be consistent with how `Array` works, and trigger a `fatalError` if invalid subscripts are given.
An alternative would to create a custom `Index` struct within `TriangularArray` that represents the triangle's indexes, and can be optionally built from a `x` and `y` value (though this could complicate things quite a bit).

PS: This answer assumes that `TriangularArray<T>` can have a triangle of an arbitrary height (a height that can be specified at runtime), as it's not specified in the question. If the height is defined at compile-time, then the bounds can be hardcoded and like @Raul Mantilla mentionned `#error` may be used.

Answer (score 0):

Only Swift 4.2 can help you mark such issues in our code, I don't think it's possible with 4.1 or less.

Swift 4.2 example:

```
#if true
   #error("add here your compiler error")
#endif
```